# jquery loop to add to variable

Tags: jquery, loops, variables, distance

I have a variable like this

```
var closestMarkers = this.FindClosestMarkers(
    geoLocation.lat(), 
    geoLocation.lng(), 
    this.distance
);
```

My problem is that this variable can be '0'. I want to create a loop that checks if `closestMarkers` is 0, and if it's 0, I want to add +50 to distance. Something like this

```
if (closestMarkers.length === 0){
    var closestMarkers = this.FindClosestMarkers(
        geoLocation.lat(), 
        geoLocation.lng(), 
        parseInt(this.distance)+50 
    );
}
```

My problem with this is that if `closestMarkers` is 0 it only adds 50 to the distance once, but after that `closestmarkers` can still be 0, if there are still no markers found within the specified distance. I want to make a loop that adds 50 to distance until `closestMarkers` are no longer 0.

Sorry for my bad explanation but I hope you understand me.

Comment: We're going to need more than that. Where is this loop?

Comment: my problem is that closestmarkers must never be 0, because I want to create a loop that adds to the value "50" on the distance until closestmarkes becomes greater than "0", you understand the problem better now? :)

Answer (score 1):

You may use ternary operator:

```
var closestMarkers = closestMarkers.length !== 0 ? 
  this.FindClosestMarkers(geoLocation.lat(), geoLocation.lng(), this.distance) 
   : 
  this.FindClosestMarkers(geoLocation.lat(), 
    geoLocation.lng(), parseInt(this.distance)+50);
```

Comment: That didnt worked.., if i logged out this.distance distance was still default(50).

Answer (score 0):

```
if (closestMarkers.length === 0){
   this.distance += 50;
    var closestMarkers = this.FindClosestMarkers(
        geoLocation.lat(), 
        geoLocation.lng(), 
        this.distance 
    );
}
```

I think you do not add up +50 to the total distance. So, you need to increase it somewhere outside of its usage.

If you want to check markers within a maximum distance, then use this:

```
tmp_distance = 0;
max_distance = 1000;
while ((closestMarkers.length === 0) && (tmp_distance < max_distance )){
   tmp_distance  += 50;
   closestMarkers = this.FindClosestMarkers(
        geoLocation.lat(), 
        geoLocation.lng(), 
        tmp_distance 
    );
}
```

you also need to remove **var** from inner {}, I think it creates a local variable and it does not affect the main *closestMarkers* variable.

Comment: will this will add 50 on the distance to closestMarkers not 0 anymore?

Comment: Sorry didn't understand your comment :).

Comment: check my answer below, it was too long to write here :(

Answer (score 0):

@salivan The problem is that I have a Google map of locations with the printed out for geolocation. However, this result may be empty if I find myself in a place in the world where there are not any of locations within the radius that the user has selected in a dropdown instance. 50km, 100km, 500km so to avoid that result in of locations becomes empty so I want that if closestmarkers is 0, I want to put on 50km of distance still to closestmarkers not 0 anymore, which ultimately could be that I put on 50km 500 times anyway to closestmarkers not 0 anymore, Google Translate translated it so you do not understand then we blame Google Translate haha :)